# Convert date in JSON to Date from String

Tags: apex, json, date

While parsing JSON response from webservices, I'm getting date field as `'03/21/2012'` in a string format. My JSON2Apex parser class is converting this value in String and I'm facing hard time converting this value in Date format.

> Illegal assignment from String to Date

```
    for(accountParser.cls_account caa : classlist){
    Account A = New Account ();
    A.Name = caa.Name;
    A.Start_Date__C = caa.Start_date; // Error: Illegal assignment from String to Date
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always convert the value again after you have parsed your JSON. Try using the [`Date.parse(...)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_date.htm#apex_System_Date_parse) method on the string.

```
A.Start_Date__C = Date.parse(caa.Start_date);
```

Comment: The potential downside with this is we don't know how the date is getting generated. This might cause problems for international visitors if the dates switch to DD/MM/YYYY or something else.

Comment: Its an important point to consider, and something I was looking into to add as an edit. The issue with `date.parse` is that both an international DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY will look valid and be parsed by `date.parse`, but without any information to tell you which one you have. Without knowing where the date is from, its equally difficult to try to manually parse the date- unless you know that the format will always be the same, in which, it doesn't really matter. Regardless, fixing the json seems the best bet, which I considered out of scope of the question.

Answer (score 1):

Technically, what you should do is fix the JSON from the source. Dates in JSON should *always* be ISO8601 format, to avoid ambiguity between DD/MM/YYYY and MM/DD/YYYY formats. If you can change the data so that your dates are always formatted as YYYY-MM-DD, you can then change Start_Date in your class so that it is a native Date object instead of a simple String. This reduces the odds of parsing errors.

Comment: @battery.cord and sfdcfox .. Thank you both.. I got this working. ...